# Switch state not linking to Label

Tags: ios

For some reason using NSUserDefaults to save the state of my switch and my label don't seem to be working. I can save the state of my switch and load it however unless i manually change the state of the switch the label will not change to on or off.

```
        NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    self->switch1.on = ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"switchKey"]

                             isEqualToString:@"On"]) ? (YES) : (NO);
```

As you can see i added in label.text = @"OFF" when the switch is off but however it still doesn't change.

```
- (IBAction)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender {

NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (sender.on == 0) {

    label.text = @"OFF";
    [standardDefaults setObject:@"Off" forKey:@"switchKey"];


} else if (sender.on == 1) {

    label.text = @"ON";
    [standardDefaults setObject:@"On" forKey:@"switchKey"];


}

[standardDefaults synchronize];

}
```

Before i wanted to save the switch state i just used this.

```
-(IBAction) alarmSettings1{

if (switch1.on)

{ label.text = @"ON";}


else { label.text = @"OFF";}

}
```

I know I'm just doing something simple wrong but can't figure out what.

Comment: why u using stringForKey? use ObjectForKey instead?

Comment: are your outlets connected?

Comment: @DianaProdan yes they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your boolean like so:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"switchKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

So when you want to set the state of your switch, you would do:

```
BOOL switchState = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"switchKey"]; 
self.switch1.on = switchState;
```

Also, in your `IBAction` method, read the state like so:

```
- (IBAction)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender {
    label.text = sender.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:sender.on forKey:@"switchKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Yes the switch does save state however the label doesn't change.

Comment: Are your outlets wired up correctly? You might need to check that you can change the state of the label at all. If that's the case, it's a matter of figuring out how you want to connect to it.

Comment: switch1 is connected to the switch, switchChanged is connected as touchupinside to the switch and label is connected to the label. however it still doesn't save the state. also self.switch.on = switchState; has to be changed to self->switch1.on = switchState to actually work otherwise there is an error

Comment: Try connecting the IBaction to the 'valueChanged:' selector.